# wordpress making a static and dynamic link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site which has a lot of links on the front page, with subsequent pages for those links. The layout of this front page is totally different than the inner pages (in terms of columns). The inner pages have the same 3-column layout.

What i have done that is i have made a page template with the left column added through:

`<?php get_template_part('sidebar','left1'); ?>`

and

`<?php get_template_part('sidebar','right1'); ?>` for the right column.

The inner content is added when i make a new page.

While adding the new page, I select the template where i added the left and right columns , and so every time i add a new page (whose link should be on the front page), I add that template and so inner pages are going fine.

The problem is that these pages that I generate are having the links on `index.php` and I cannot link the newly formed pages to the front page.

Also, how can I add links to PHP pages that are not generated, but part of the themes file?

So what I'm asking is:

1. How to link to static pages in PHP files that are part of the theme,
2. As how can I link to dymically created pages (Page -> Add New) within the PHP files of the theme.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You know there is other markup than CAPS?

Comment: some one pls help,i am tired of not solving this one, as you can see i am new to wordpress i exhaustedly searched the codex for this, but no solution

Comment: Let me give you a word of advice: Nobody will help you if you don't follow the rules. Using caps excessively is annoying, but it is even worse to let people work for you without honoring their answers by - at least - accepting them. It shouldn't be too hard to click the green tick next to the answer.

Comment: @still_learning, just for the record, the second green tick is mine